# Can I buy a VIA Rail bike box without travelling by VIA Rail?

Tags: trains, canada, bicycles

I'm travelling with my bicycle but not by train.  I need a bike box.  Most bike boxes available from bike shops are too small for my bicycle, but I'm told VIA Rail boxes are very large (large enough for my bicycle).  Can I buy a VIA Rail box without travelling on a VIA Rail train?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**VIA Rail no longer sells bike boxes.**

The baggage staff at Toronto Union Station has confirmed to me orally that VIA Rail has stopped to sell bike boxes.  Travellers who wish to take their bicycle as checked luggage do not need to pack their bicycle in any way.

Greyhound does still sell bike boxes at 10$ each, to travellers or non-travellers.  Dimensions are 26 cm x 89 cm x 143 cm.  It does **not** fit a normal bicycle with the wheels still on.  I can barely fit my bicycle if I take the front wheel off; for a touring bicycle that has fenders, luggage racks, lights etc., it is not a convenient alternative.

Answer (score 2):

[Via Rail baggage policy](http://canadadetrem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Politicas-de-Bagagem.pdf) lists "Bicycle box (for non-travellers)" for $20 "available in certain stations only".

Also, https://greyhound.ca/en/ticketsandtravel/baggageinformation.aspx

> Bicycle boxes are available from Greyhound Courier Express at selected terminals for $10 each (plus GST).

Perhaps the Greyhound box is large enough too.

Comment: Hmm, why is that baggage policy linked on a 4 year old blog post in Portuguese and not on VIA Rail itself...?  Anyway, I'll go by the station tomorrow and ask.

Comment: The current policy posted to VIA Rail is less detailed. The PDF seems legit however, six year old or not.

Comment: Their policy might have changed.  I have the forture of living in a large city so I can try both Via and Greyhound.

Comment: VIA Rail no longer sells bicycle boxes.  I finally got my box at Greyhound.  Will confirm dimensions later.

Answer (score 1):

I just phoned VIA rail and apparently any manned station has boxes or will provide a bag for your bike if they are out of boxes.